# Is there a repeating, vibrating timer app for the iPhone that supports app-switching?

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation, alarm

When studying, I used to use one of those cheap digital kitchen timers that chirps every ten minutes as a little reminder of how fast time was passing -- it helped me keep track of time without the temptation to constantly glance at the clock.

The kitchen timer gave out on me recently, so I've been looking for an iPhone app to replace it. Ideally, it would have an on and off setting, and when on, would periodically vibrate in my pocket every ten or fifteen minutes.

Unfortunately, the apps I've found are quite chintzy and don't support switching between apps, or stop as soon as the phone is set to sleep -- and either of these is a deal breaker.

Are there any iPhone apps out there do what I'm looking for?

(I've been burned by a couple of paid apps that turned out to be lemons, so I'd be most grateful.)

Comment: So something like this http://www.theverge.com/2014/1/30/5361210/skrekkogle-durr-the-watch-without-a-face but in app form?

Comment: Exactly, an app that makes the phone vibrate at regular intervals as a reminder of passing time.

Comment: So you want something like a tabata timer that vibrates?

Answer (score 4):

Periodic Timer is exactly what you need: https://apps.apple.com/lt/app/periodic-timer/id933241656.

Comment: It even has an Apple Watch version! :D

Comment: If you want this timer to just vibrate, turn off the sound with hardware switch on the device.

Comment: @kelin Link is dead... :-(

Comment: @Samoth, thank you! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use an interval timer like this. [IntervalTimer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/interval-timer-timing-for/id406473568?mt=8)

Just customize it to your needs and don't care about the high and low intensity options it has. If you adjust them you can have a perfect vibrating timer

Comment: I like that this is simple, just I wish I could turn off the sound and have it just vibrate.

Answer (score -3):

if you're looking for a great and simple interval timer this one's one of the best
https://appsto.re/us/U8427.i

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.  Also, if you're affiliated with that software, site rules require you to indicate that in the answer.